# Adding numbers using Excel Forms

Tags: excel, textbox, vba

I have created an Excel form which has five text boxes. These TextBoxes accept any numerical value. Once the five numbers have been entered there is a sixth Textbox that shows the sum of these values. The sum of these values should always be 100%. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

Dim Value As Single

Value = Val(TextBox1.Value) + Val(TextBox2.Value) + Val(TextBox3.Value) + Val(TextBox4.Value) + Val(TextBox5.Value)

TextBox6.Value = Value

End Sub
```

I have the same code for all Text-box change events. Unfortunately this is not working. When I enter `10`, `20`, `30`, `40` as my input, instead of displaying `100%` it shows `10203040` as the result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is wrong is your expectation that the sum of five values should be 100%.  When you sum five values you're going to get the sum of the values.  If you want a percentage, than you have to compare the sum to some other value.  You want the sum as a percentage of what exactly?

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. I am summing up 5 values and I am checking if it's 100 or not. If its not, I am displaying an error. The problem I have is just with the summing part. I don't think the Val function I am using is converting the text to numbers.

Comment: Your code works for me.  Can you provide any more detail?

Comment: Ah gotcha... I was a bit confused.  I thought you were expecting TextBox6 to show 100%.

Comment: Since `Value` is a single, `TextBox1.Value` to `TextBox5.Value` would automatically be converted to numeric.  The `Val` is not strictly necessary.

Comment: Do you have `TextBox4_Change()` routine with different code?

Comment: It's the same code. Any change in any textbox I want the same result. I want them to sum up and display in the Total

Comment: For you the values of `TextBox1.Value` to `TextBox4.Value` are being concatenated.  I do not know any way of achieving that effect.  It is as though `+` has been overload to match `&` but VBA does not have overload.

Comment: @TonyDallimore Yeah I'm confused to.  It seems like it should work as it is originally.

Comment: @BrianPressler.  I have created a workbook and a user form with 6 text boxes and have copied in the code above.  It works perfectly for me.  Even if there was a non-standard `Val` function I cannot think how to achieve concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the function you need to use is `CDbl` or `CSng` which converts to a double or single floating point numbers.  It won't handle blanks or non-numeric data entered so you might need to check for invalid data entered first.  Something like this should work:

```
Value = 0
If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Value) Then Value = Value + CSng(TextBox1.Value)
If IsNumeric(TextBox2.Value) Then Value = Value + CSng(TextBox2.Value)
If IsNumeric(TextBox3.Value) Then Value = Value + CSng(TextBox3.Value)
If IsNumeric(TextBox4.Value) Then Value = Value + CSng(TextBox4.Value)
If IsNumeric(TextBox5.Value) Then Value = Value + CSng(TextBox5.Value)

TextBox6.Value = Value
```

Comment: When I execute the CDbl code, it says type mismatch and does not execute the code.

Comment: You might have to check for invalid data entered before including it in the sum.  I updated my answer to show how you can do that.

Comment: `IIf` doesn't short-circuit: it will always evaluate both the True and False parts.  In the Immediate window `? iif(true, "OK", 1/0)` gives a "division by zero" error...